# How to access Parent Window Elements in Child Page

Tags: javascript

I have a Main page(Parent) and one pop up page(Child Page) on it, i want to pass an XML string from Parent page to Child page. when i tried to do it with query string i got this following Error.

"A Potentially dangerous Request.QueryString value was detected from the client"

Can any one knows others ways to pass data from Parent to child page.

Thanks in Advance
 Nitesh katare

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to pass a string, why don't you declare a global function in the parent window?

```
PARENT PAGE
<script>
var my_string = '';
function set_string( x ) { 
  my_string = x;
}
</script>
```

Then calling the function from the child page is simple:

```
CHILD PAGE
<script>
parent.set_string( "whatever" );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your popup you could call

```
window.opener.<your function>(<the xml>)
```